# How to create Avro schema for JSON with dot in the key name

Tags: json, avro, fluent-bit

I have a JSON log that I am converting into Avro format and then with Fluentbit feeding into Kafka. The Avro schema that I create does not capture the field with "." and when I try to define the field with "." in the `name` I get `Illegal character in: source.ip`

here is the sample JSON

```
{
    "user_agent": [
        "One",
        "Two"
    ],
    "@timestamp": "2023-12-06T11:29:41+05:30",
    "source.ip": "12.34.56.78",
    "http.request.remote_ip": "4.3.2.1"
}
```

this is the Avro schema that I could muster but it does not work

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "jsonRecord",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "user_agent",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": "string"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "timestamp",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "source",
            "type": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "source",
                "namespace": "source",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "ip",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "http",
            "type": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "request",
                "namespace": "http.request",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "remote_ip",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

What would be the correct AVRO schema for this JSON structure?